# how to change matplotlib pie size to keep align with other plot windows

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, axis, subplot

I have created 3 plots, two line graphs and one pie chart.

And I found these plots have different height, pie is in square, while line graph is not.
How can I align the heights of all three graphs?

See [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjKK.png).

```
    #Init:
    self.ui.figure, self.ui.axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
    self.ui.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.ui.figure)
    self.ui.QVLayout.addWidget(self.ui.canvas)

    #Draw:
    axes1 = self.ui.axes[0]
    axes2 = self.ui.axes[1]
    axes3 = self.ui.axes[2]

    self.ui.axes[0].cla()
    self.ui.axes[1].cla()
    self.ui.axes[2].cla()

    color = self.ui.cmbBoxColorSelect.currentText()

    xl = np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1, dtype=np.float64)
    x = np.arange(0, 4, dtype=np.float64)
    y = np.arange(0, 4, dtype=np.float64)
    #Plot1
    ...

    axes1.set_title('Saturation', fontsize=10, pad=1)
    axes1.plot(xl, xl, '-k', linewidth=1.0)
    self.line_sat = axes1.plot(x, y, '-bs', linewidth=1.0)[0]

    #Plot2
    ...

    axes2.set_title('Luma', fontsize=10, pad=1)
    axes2.plot(xl * 125, xl * 125, '-k', linewidth=1.0)
    self.line_luma = axes2.plot(x, y, '-bs', linewidth=1.0)[0]

    #Pie
    ...

    axes3.pie(
        value, radius=1, labels=label,startangle=red_angle,
        autopct='', frame=True, colors=colors, labeldistance=1.0)

    self.ui.figure.tight_layout()
    self.ui.canvas.draw()
    self.ui.canvas.flush_events()
```

I'd like to make all plots to be of the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set sharey to True as third parameter

```
self.ui.figure, self.ui.axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
```

Comment: this is not works, and a litte strange, see picture below,